# How do I execute Python 2.7 and above in Bash commandline?

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I am learning python and using idle. But I wanted to know how I can execute python programs of 2.7 and 3 in the Bash terminal. Is that possible?

I'd like to be able to execute them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will often type any of the following lines in order to run my programs under the correct version.

```
python27 path/to/file.py
python3 path/to/file.py
python34 path/to/file.py
```

This requires that each of those versions be installed.